# What is the format of an iterable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterable

I am learning about iteration in es6 and i understand what it does. However, i constantly come across the words "it returns an iterable". If an object looks like this { } and an array like this [ ] etc can someone please show me what a iterable looks like. Thanks

Comment: Don't hesitate to read the docs as they are pretty clear: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: The question doesn't really have much sense, `iterable` is more like a property than a raw type, you cannot represent it by a definition syntax. By the way, avoid thinking in terms of "looks like" when talking about "syntax to define a type of object".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baiscally an *iterable* is a value, even a primitive value where [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) is implemented.

For example an array has this by default, like

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log(...array);
```

But if you add the iterator, for example, to the prototype of `Number`, you could even spread numbers.

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
};

console.log(...10);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Examples are always best.

Answer (score 0):

Iterable means an object (an array is also an object) that has the function `Symbol.iterator`. To simply test whether an object is iterable or not, you can try to use the spread operator on it

example
[image: iterable example]
To understand how iterable works
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Answer (score 0):

An iterable by itself is not a data structure (like an array or an object). Instead it is a property function of an object which defines *how* the object is iterable.

See [Iteration Protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) for details:

> The iterable protocol allows JavaScript objects to define or customize their iteration behavior, such as what values are looped over in a for..of construct. Some built-in types are built-in iterables with a default iteration behavior, such as Array or Map, while other types (such as Object) are not.

Answer (score 0):

When they are saying "it will return iterable" that means you can use it in the for...of loop to iterate that Object. As we know that Plain JS Object is not iterable. Below are the iterables values:
1.Arrays
2.Strings
3.Maps
4.Sets
**An iterable is a data structure that wants to make its elements accessible to the public. It does so by implementing a method whose key is Symbol.iterator. That method is a factory for iterators.**

Answer (score -1):

Iterable is interface, not data structure. You can read more [here](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html)

Comment: Perhaps giving an explanation that is back up with a documentation link would have been better answer.

Comment: You are right, but I presumed that he has read documentation. I found explanation in this blog good for layman so I thought it might be useful.